# code is not printing out anything, I get no result when I run program in python

Tags: python

I have a code that when you input players and their bowling scores it then organizes them into 3 list and prints out some remarks but when I run the program nothing prints out

```
def isGreater(name1,name2):

    length=0

    if(len(name1)<len(name2)):

        length=len(name1)

    else:

        length=len(name2)

    for i in range(0,length):

        if(ord(name1[i])>ord(name2[i])):

            return True

        elif (ord(name1[i])<ord(name2[i])):

            return False

def scoresData():

    data=[]

    while True:

        player=input("Enter the Name and Score of a Player : ")

        if(player==''):

            break

        data.append(player.split());

    print("----------------------------------")

    print("\tEntered Order::\nPlayer Name \t Score")

    print("----------------------------------")

    for player in data:

        print(player[0],"\t\t",player[1])

    print()

    for i in range(0,len(data)+1):

        for j in range(0,len(data)-i-1):

            if(isGreater(data[j][0],data[j+1][0])):

                temp=data[j]

                data[j]=data[j+1]

                data[j+1]=temp

    print("----------------------------------")

    print("\tAplhabetical Order::\nPlayer Name \t Score")

    print("----------------------------------")

    for y in data:

        print(y[0],"\t\t",y[1])

    print()

    for i in range(0,len(data)):

        for j in range(0,len(data)-1):

            if(int(data[j][1])<int(data[j+1][1])):

                temp=data[j]

                data[j]=data[j+1]

                data[j+1]=temp

    print("----------------------------------")

    print("\tScore Order::\nPlayer Name \t Score")

    print("----------------------------------")

    tot=0

    for x in data:

        print(x[0],"\t\t",x[1])

        tot=tot+int(x[1])

    print()

    print("Congratulations! Mr/Ms."+data[0][0]," You scored highest of ",data[0][1],".")

    print("Oh! Mr/Ms."+data[-1][0]," Sorry to say that scored minimum of ",data[-1][1],".")

    print("Average of scores \t:: ",int(tot/len(data)))
```

Trying to figure out why it is not printing out any results what so ever. I am not getting any error either.

Comment: Do you ever call either of those functions?

Comment: add `scoresData()` and run your script. Code works fine, no errors.

Comment: Wow got so caught up I missed it. Thank you! pretty embarrassing

Answer (score 1):

I've been so free to write code to correct incorrect manual input like "pete10" where it should be "pete 10". As it was not obvious in your code that it needed white-spacing or tab.

Suggestion to replace:

```
for player in data:

        print(player[0],"\t\t",player[1])
```

With:

```
    index = 0

    print ('all data : %s' % data)

    for player in data:
        print ('player data: %s' % player)
        try:
            print(player[0],"\t\t",player[1])
            index += 1
        except:
            incorrect_name = str(data[index])[2:-2]
#            print ('name is incorrect : %s' % incorrect_name)
            player_corrected = []
            player_name  = ''
            player_score = ''
            for char in incorrect_name:
#                print (char)
                if char.isalpha():           # checks for alphabet letters
                    player_name += char
                else:                        # here you can check for other character 
                                             # types if other than integers.
                    player_score += char
            player_corrected = [player_name, int(player_score)]
            print ('correced player data : %s.' % player_corrected)
            data[index]= player_corrected
#            print (data)
```

Finally to start your script:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    scoresData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function.
When you do

```
def xxyyzz():
    xx
    yy
```

You are only defining the function. To run it do:

```
xxyyzz()
```

below. Or on your case:

```
scoresData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end of your file:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    scoresData()
```